# For which positive real numbers $a$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{\log n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know the answer is $a<1$. I tried the ratio test which was inconclusive, and also the root test which did not work. Any tips on how to proceed?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hint: $a^{\log n}=e^{\log a\cdot\log n}=\dots$

Comment: The answer $a<1$ is actually wrong. The correct one is $a<1/e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$ a^{\log n} = \exp( \log a \log n) = n^{\log a }  $$

Notice that $log a > 0$ iff $a > 1 $. Thus $\sum a^{\log n }$ diverges if $a \geq 1$ and converges when $ log a < -1 $ or when $ a < 1/e $

Comment: Series $n^c$ converges for $c<-1$, not $c<0$.

Comment: fixed it now...